# Query Mongoose Hash Map with array of properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose document and schema called csgoItems like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56ff8fb815ad7ecdede3bc3c"
    },
    "csgo_number": 1,
    "last_updated": 1459589048324,
    "items": {
        "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Well-Worn)": {
            "market_hash_name": "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Well-Worn)",
            "sale_price": 134.29
        },
        "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Minimal Wear)": {
            "market_hash_name": "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Minimal Wear)",
            "sale_price": 108.3
        },
        "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Field-Tested)": {
            "market_hash_name": "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Field-Tested)",
            "sale_price": 79.73
        },
        "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Battle-Scarred)": {
            "market_hash_name": "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Battle-Scarred)",
            "sale_price": 73.17
        },
        "Shadow Daggers | Stained (Well-Worn)": {
            "market_hash_name": "Shadow Daggers | Stained (Well-Worn)",
            "sale_price": 113.25
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use an array of market_hash_names to return a list of items with only those market hash names like so

```
var searchItems = ["Shadow Daggers | Stained (Well-Worn)", "Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked (Battle-Scarred)"]
```

I have tried this

```
    csgoItems.find({"items": {$in: searchItems}}, function(err, found){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(found);
        }
```

How can I achieve these results?

Comment: You'd be better off changing your schema to get your data out of your keys and make `items` an array.

Comment: The reason I'm not doing it this way is because this 'items' object has thousands of items. For performance, I'd rather use a hash/map to see if the value exists rather than looping through the entire array and checking each object

Comment: Understood, but if you index the field you need to search on in the array, you can still find individual elements quickly. It's really the only way to do this right.

Comment: Ah, okay perhaps i'll go this way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query did not work because the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator only works with arrays.

To filter the query results based off the properties of the hash, you'll need to use MongoDB's [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)

A simple solution would be:

1. **Define a function to transform the hash map to an array**

   ```
   function hashToArray(hash) {
     return Object.keys(hash).map(function(key) {
       return hash[key];
     });
   }
   ```
2. **Define the options for the mapReduce query**

   The `hashToArray` function will be used to transform the `items` hash to an Array for each of the documents.

   ```
   var options = {};
   options.map = function (){ 
     emit(this._id, hashToArray(this.items), 1);
   }
   options.reduce = function (key, values){ 
     return values[0];
   }
   ```
3. **Execute the map reduce and run your query against the result**

   ```
   csgoItems.mapReduce(options, function(err, model, stats) {
     model.find({"items.market_hash_name": {$in: searchItems}},   function(err, foundItems){
       // use the result
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Great, this worked. I may reconsider and go Johnny's way and index the properties. Thank you.